# Regular Expression To Parse Shortcode data not getting closing tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm in the process of writing a parser for shortcodes.  I have a regular expression that I've been playing with to retrieve ALL shortcodes within given text.

For example I have shortcodes like this

```
[url href="http://somedomain.com" class="123"]
[snip category="spoons"]
```

my regex works fine for the above shortcodes but fails for this type

```
[widget id="23"]Body Text[/widget]
```

I'm looking to return an array like this...

```
[url href="http://somedomain.com" class="123"]
[snip category="spoons"]
[widget id="23"]Body Text[/widget]
```

then I'll loop through each shortcode and parse them individually with a separate function.  Below is the regex that i've been using.

```
"/\[(.*?)(.+?)\]/" <--works fine for no closing tags
```

and i tried this for the closing tags but it returns weird results

```
"/\[(.*?)(.+?)\](?:(.+?)?\[\/(.*?)\])?/" <--- Doesn't work well/at all
```

any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmmm, seems to match: https://regex101.com/r/lV7DsI/1

Comment: Assuming you're looking to grab the attributes and their values as well, you can use [`(?:\[\s*([\w-]+)|\G(?!\A))\s*([\w-]+)\s*=\s*([^\s\]]+?)(?=\s|\s*\])(?:\s*\](?:(.*?)\[\/\1\])?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/7PSdTf/4)

Comment: kchason - that regex places the [/widget] in a separate array key. It's not together with it's start tag.  ctwheels - this gives too many chunks of data.  I just need ALL codes in 1 array

Comment: @joeb you can remove all the extra stuff I put in there, but it does what you want.

Comment: @ctwheels - man I wish it were that easy.  I don't even know where to begin with that regex.  Beyond my pay grade.

Comment: @joeb just use `\[\s*([\w-]+)[^\]]*\](?:.*?\[\/\1\])?`

Comment: here's what i get when i use that regex. 
array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "[mycode foo="bar""
    [1]=>
    string(12) " bar="bing"]"
    [2]=>
    string(22) "[myshortcode foo="bar""
    [3]=>
    string(12) " bar="bing"]"
    [4]=>
    string(22) "[myshortcode foo="bar""
    [5]=>
    string(12) " bar="bing"]"
  }

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a built-in function ([`get_shortcode_regex()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_shortcode_regex/)) that returns the official regex that is used to parse shortcodes. My feeling is that you'd want to use that instead of rolling your own.

You can use the regex it returns to do with what you like.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I saw 'shortcodes' and assumed. No worries.